# storyboardやxibを使わずにプログラムでCollectionViewCellを作る方法

Tags: swift, ios, xcode7

プログラム初心者です。

xcode7のswift2を使用しています。
現在、CollectionViewCellをプログラムで作ろうと思っていますが、やり方がわかりません。
プログラムのみでCollectionViewを作る方法はたくさん見つかるのですが。。。

CollectionViewの場合、ImageならImageのCellを並べたり、LabelならLabel(あるいはImageとLabelの混合)を並べるというように、同じ構成のCellを並べますよね？
私は2つのCellは画像とボタン、3つののCellはラベルとボタンというように異なる構成？Cellを並べたいのです。

そのためにはCollectionViewCellを配置することが必要だと思うのですが、どなたかプログラムで配置する方法を教えてください。

説明が不十分かもしれませんが、宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CollectionViewCellを定義してCollectionViewからregisterClassを行えばできます。

Comment: ありがとうございます！できました